# Is there any way to change the image from course header using Google Classroom API?

Tags: google-classroom

I'd like to change the image on header of many Google Classroom courses, to announce an event. But to do this on web, one by one on hundred of courses, is an irksome job. It would be great if there was a way to do this by coding, but I couldn't find on Google API Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, what you want cannot be achieved.

What you can do instead, is to file a **Feature Request** on Issue Tracker by following the link [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191645&template=823908) and providing all the necessary details.

#### Reference

- [Classroom API Support](https://developers.google.com/classroom/support).

Comment: Thank you very much!